# 404 issue with setting a postgres database path

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, http-status-code-404, psql

I've been trying to figure out how i am formatting my database path wrong. I have tried many different ways but all give back a 404.

```
#models.py

import os
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, create_engine
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json

database_name = "trivia"
database_path = "postgres://{}:{}@{}/{}".format('postgres', 'password', 'localhost:5432', database_name)

db = SQLAlchemy()

def setup_db(app, database_path=database_path):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_path
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
    db.create_all()
```

my database set up just to show that i have it set up and that my database name is actually called 'trivia':

```
    $ psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql (12.1)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \c trivia
You are now connected to database "trivia" as user "postgres".
trivia=# \dt
           List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  |  Owner
--------+------------+-------+----------
 public | categories | table | postgres
 public | questions  | table | postgres
(2 rows)
trivia=# \d
                List of relations
 Schema |       Name        |   Type   |  Owner
--------+-------------------+----------+----------
 public | categories        | table    | postgres
 public | categories_id_seq | sequence | postgres
 public | questions         | table    | postgres
 public | questions_id_seq  | sequence | postgres
(4 rows)
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What makes you sure that there is something wrong with the database connection? I would expect a HTTP response with a status code 5xx (at least in development mode) if there is something wrong with the database. The status code 404 may indicate that there is no endpoint at the given URI.

Comment: @momo Here is my git rep if you're willing to take a look. I assumed there was something wrong with my database because nothing wants to display. https://github.com/marissawatkins/Trivia_API

Comment: Which API call do you trigger?